# Soft body simulation with rigged characters, blender 2.9

Tags: cloth-simulation, soft-body

I'm working on setting up a soft body simulation in Blender, where I have a rigged character but I want some parts of the body to deform with collision.

I checked out a quick tutorial online, I enabled cloth physics, then created a pinned vertex group for the areas I don't want to move.

It works (i.e., the unpinned area now responds to physics), but I have a problem - the rigging no longer works. The character now completely ignores the skeleton and is simply frozen in place.

In the tutorials, the skeleton still works properly with the simulation enabled. Why is my skeleton suddenly being ignored? What am I missing?

--

There is an alternative method of enabling soft body then setting the vertex group you don't want to move under the "goal". This seems to not work at all, in other words, the soft body is totally ignored. I know some simulation is happening because my scene slows down to a crawl, but from the perspective of my character, collisions and other soft body functions (jiggling body parts as the character moves) are totally ignored.

--

Also, there at lots of tutorials on how to do this in previous versions of blender (for example, like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DiO52a-iK_k) but nothing for 2.8 or 2.9. Did they break / remove this for 2.8/2.9?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have the modifiers in the correct order? *Armature* first, then *Cloth* (top-down)?

Comment: Definitely, that was how I set it up.